# How to change button CSS click / drag color?

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, button

You can checkout my website here: https://www.counterboosting.com/buy-csgo-rank-boosting/

When dragging the "Buy Now" button, it will randomly turn green. If anyone could help me keep it orange as it is. Thanks!

```css
.col-boosting .btn-pay-rank {
 height: 65px;
 font-weight: bold;
 background: #e06b38;
 border: none;
 box-shadow: 0 7px 0 0 #c7511f;
}

.col-boosting .btn-pay-rank:hover {
 height: 65px;
 background: #dd5a22;
 font-weight: bold;
 border: none;
 box-shadow: 0 7px 0 0 #c7511f;
}

.col-boosting .btn-pay-rank[disabled] {
 height: 65px;
 font-weight: bold;
 background: #e06b38;
 border: none;
 box-shadow: 0 7px 0 0 #c7511f;
}

.col-boosting .btn-default {
 height: 65px;
 font-weight: bold;
 background: #e06b38;
 border: none;
 box-shadow: 0 7px 0 0 #c7511f;
}

.col-boosting .btn {
 height: 65px;
 font-weight: bold;
 background: #e06b38;
 border: none;
 box-shadow: 0 7px 0 0 #c7511f;
}

.col-boosting .btn-primary {
 height: 65px;
 font-weight: bold;
 background: #e06b38;
 border: none;
 box-shadow: 0 7px 0 0 #c7511f;
}

.col-boosting .btn-pay-rank-primary:hover, .col-boosting .btn-pay-rank-primary:focus, .col-boosting .btn-pay-rank-primary:active, .col-boosting .btn-pay-rank-primary.active, .open > .dropdown-toggle.btn-pay-rank-primary {
 height: 65px;
 font-weight: bold;
 background: #e06b38;
 border: none;
 box-shadow: 0 7px 0 0 #c7511f;
}

.col-boosting .btn-primary:hover, .btn-primary:focus, .btn-primary:active, .btn-primary.active, .open > .dropdown-toggle.btn-primary {
 height: 65px;
 font-weight: bold;
 background: #e06b38;
 border: none;
 box-shadow: 0 7px 0 0 #c7511f;
}

.col-boosting .btn-primary:active, .col-boosting .btn-primary.active {
 height: 65px;
 font-weight: bold;
 background: #e06b38;
 border: none;
 box-shadow: 0 7px 0 0 #c7511f;
}
```

As you can see, I pretty much tried everything and I can't seem to find a solution. Some help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a [**link to a site or an example**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it), if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Comment: alright I understand, I still need to pick someone as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have rule that you need to override

```
.btn-success:hover,
.btn-success:focus,
.btn-success.focus,
.btn-success:active,
.btn-success.active,
.open>.dropdown-toggle.btn-success {
  color: #fff;
   background-color: #449d44;
   border-color: #398439;
}
```

this rule makes your button green when it's active/focused. So you need or to overwrite it or to include it in your button's style, style for focus and active states.

You can try something like this:

```
.col-boosting .btn-pay-rank:hover,
.col-boosting .btn-pay-rank:focus,
.col-boosting .btn-pay-rank:active {
   height: 65px;
   background: #dd5a22;
   font-weight: bold;
   border: 0;
   box-shadow: 0 7px 0 0 #c7511f;
}
```

This should work.

HTH.

Comment: Thank you so much! Despite the 3 downvotes I got on my post, you still found an answer for me. It works perfectly, thanks!